# How to create unique instances of devices with AVD

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I am a software tester and I need to be able to create "unique" simulated devices for testing our client's android application. The app I am testing is for device security and it recognizes if the (virtual) device has been registered in its system before. Right now, it stops the registration process as it detects that the avd created device has been used before (even if I delete and create a new instance).

Is there a way to create a unique device each time so the app will see it as new and allow the registration to continue?

Mike

Comment: How do you determine if the app has been executed before? SharedPreferences?

Comment: an avd is supposed to be unique if its port no. is different than what u used before...i.e default is 5554, make another avd, run it without closing 5554 , it will run on port no. 5556, and so on, u can test this way ...Got the hint?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IMEI as unique identifier it looks like its possible but not easy. More like a hack.
Following page describes how to change IMEI in an emulator: 
http://codepainters.wordpress.com/2009/12/11/android-imei-number-and-the-emulator/